# Upload to D2L LOR Failing with Permission Error

Tags: desire2learn

In trying to upload a scorm package via the REST API the upload is not working.

PUT /d2l/api/lr/(D2LVERSION: version)/objects/
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/lor.html

We are always refused based on 403 permission.

Are there any settings I should look at? Also looking for a trace of this working.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the account you are authenticated with can perform the function in the web UI it is expected that the API will also function.

If you are getting keys back from the login process but this call is failing you could try a basic call from the sample such as "whoami". If that works your keys are correct.

If the keys are correct and some GET calls are working, you may need to pass a different method to the signing call in the sdk. (The method is part of the signature).

Here is an example of a working trace. 403 errors often have a body that will provide additional information.  Note the security parameters are:  x_a,x_b,x_c,x_d,x_t parameters on the call.

```
PUT http://smihai-7:44459/d2l/api/LR/1.0/objects/?repositoryId=1&x_t=1339183935&x_a=L2Hd9WvDTcyiyu5n2AEgpg&x_c=tfJFhSUaczOeOGqDFPXPq8NSBPj2sOhz4U3RacqWRMY&x_b=TestToken&x_d=BEl7kdCcrjenkpBt9ri5dkt4bdEgCo6xfZDWIpkKctA HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp 101.3.0.0
Host: smihai-7:44459
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Content-Length: 1203
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Resource"; filename="Hello World Module.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
PK???u?h?]G?g???????????Hello World Topic.htmlM??
?@??A??wwo?xH+???h????b
[o+ ????oD??RYW9u??????}J,?q
d2?[!%E|Crj?Wo{34??Xg??s???L?3??+??/?????*??W?W3?Fyb    w?>?cR?Zrf?*???b??PK???u?h?N2?T??n?????imsmanifest.xml?V??0?#?Q??m@TI?.b    ?XF??5?????k,?$~???6I??Vt??s?=g?x???%7)??J?i4   P?f\???????????DR?W`]?(?WL???g??d???s?,.&i?q????r??jT?kI??E?C?fsmd6-?q??G?  .?f?i??4???!??v\???o?7$\jH%
??K??~P??m?`E?¥a)?C????v???6????@???U~?????x???[fe?.?3????~W???;B_?,???V@B?HE???:??q?e???s??_E? 1wK??<R????T??.9YE??SkP`?????*UT??3???j??#'??#2?;?e_c?@g.????}?p?>?c??????\?
????~,u????\s?M*L?U???E??
??????Kzp\E?X@?%\p???\??R
X-????%??C??????7?|??/&?=???h????l?\?\???????P???s??))??Td??K?????{?Y?+????v?gTN??h$?
?E'E?aB?UD????PK-????u?h?]G?g?????????????????????????Hello World Topic.htmlPK-????u?h?N2?T??n???????????????????imsmanifest.xmlPK??????????E????
-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

And the response is like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 69
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2012 19:32:22 GMT
{"IdentId":4,"Version":1,"ExecutionMessage":null,"ExecutionStatus":0}
```